# Facing issue with git clone command on mac OS catalina

Tags: git, macos, github, gitlab, ssh-keys

After Mac OS updated to Catalina, facing issue with git clone from my git repo

inspite of using correct username and password for cloning, still getting below error

remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/My_Repo.git'

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. You will probably get a better answer on AskDifferent Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Git is a programming tool, so I think this is actually on-topic here (although not necessarily a good question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first:

- your [credential-osxkeychain](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain) for any GitHub credentials
- your account to check if you [have 2FA activated](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa), which would mean your password would need to be a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line)

The [OP Mahendra Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7225479/mahendra-sahu) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59433837/facing-issue-with-git-clone-command-on-mac-os-catalina/59434834?noredirect=1#comment105068421_59434834):

> For 2FA activated account, you need a PAT (Personal Access Token)

Comment: @MahendraSahu What was the issue? cached crednetials in the osxkeychain? Or 2FA activated, meaning you needed a PAT? (Personal Access Token)

Comment: For 2FA activated account, you need a  PAT (Personal Access Token).

Comment: @MahendraSahu Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.